# Angular resource timing out

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql

I'm having an issue where I'm calling a database query from my backend via the page controller and if the function doesn't return instantaneously in the backend controller, then an error is hit in the page controller. It's beyond my knowledge which side is the culprit: angular or nodejs?

FYI, the backend route works when I manually type it in, and the function in page controller is successful if the query is very very small and returns almost instantly.

**PageController**

```
    $scope.getItem = function(item) {
      Item.item_query({ itemId: itemId}, function(result) {
        console.log("result" + result);
      }, function(err) {
        console.log("err" + err);
      });
    };
```

**Resource service**

```
 window.app.factory("Item", function ($resource) {
   return $resource('api/:action/:itemId',{},
     {
        get_item_files: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            params: {
                action: 'items'
            }
        },

        item_query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            params: {
                action: 'items',
                itemId: '@itemId'
            },
            cache: false
        }
    });
```

});

**Backend Controller**

```
exports.getItem = function(req, res) {
  var itemId = req.params.itemId;
  var query = "SELECT c.name, * FROM  (\
               SELECT p.champion_id\
                    , count(p.item0 = ? OR NULL)::int2 AS it0\
                    , count(p.item1 = ? OR NULL)::int2 AS it1\
                    , count(p.item2 = ? OR NULL)::int2 AS it2\
                    , count(p.item3 = ? OR NULL)::int2 AS it3\
                    , count(p.item4 = ? OR NULL)::int2 AS it4\
                    , count(p.item5 = ? OR NULL)::int2 AS it5\
               FROM   matchversion   mv\
               CROSS  JOIN matchtype mt\
               JOIN   match          m  USING (matchtype_id,          matchversion_id)\
               JOIN   participant    p  USING (match_id)\
               WHERE  mv.matchversion = \'5.14\'\
               AND    mt.matchtype = \'RANKED_SOLO_5x5\'\
               AND    p.winner = True\
               GROUP  BY p.champion_id\
               HAVING count(p.item0 = ? OR NULL)::int2 > 0\
               OR count(p.item1 = ? OR NULL)::int2 > 0\
               OR count(p.item2 = ? OR NULL)::int2 > 0\
               OR count(p.item3 = ? OR NULL)::int2 > 0\
               OR count(p.item4 = ? OR NULL)::int2 > 0\
               OR count(p.item5 = ? OR NULL)::int2 > 0\
               ) p\
            JOIN  champion c USING (champion_id)";
  var bindings = [itemId, itemId, itemId, itemId, itemId, itemId, itemId,
                itemId,itemId,itemId,itemId,itemId]
  return pg.raw(query, bindings).then(function(resp) {
    return resp.rows;
  }).then(function(rows) {
      res.jsonp(rows);
  }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
  });
```

}

**Backend Routes**

```
var items = require('../app/controllers/itemBackend');
app.get('/api/items/:itemId', items.getItem);
```

Comment: Open your dev tools and see if the request even reaches the back end. What is the error code?

Comment: There is a request, with a few provisional headers. It says it failed to load response data.

Comment: What is the status code?

Comment: There is no status code. I just tried it again and saw that it was "cancelled by angular".

Comment: Could be a CORS issue. Are there any errors printed in the console?

Comment: Nope, none. The query goes through if it's small though. The one I'm trying to do lasts 3 seconds and it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Something I completely forgot to post was the actual HTML. Upon clicking a link, I had an href and an ng-click. If the query lasted too long, then the href took over and cancelled it.